# RPi pin not controlling NPN transistor as expected

Tags: transistors, raspberry-pi

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to control an ESC and would like to be able to turn it on and off at will using a [TIP3055 NPN transistor](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TIP3055-D.PDF).

I've hooked everything up as diagrammed below. The 11 V battery runs through a distribution board that provides several 11 V lines and a regulated 5 V line which will power the RPi in the future. As for now, it's powered via a separate USB connection.

If I manually disconnect and reconnect the wire to GPIO20, the transistor works as expected. If I leave the wire connect and turn the pin on and off with software, the ESC maintains power the entire time. I thought maybe power was being forced from the transistor to the GPIO pin (as the wire reads ~2 V when connected) so I put a diode between the resistor and the pin but that had no effect.

At this point I'm fairly certain that I shouldn't have used this particular transistor. I believe I should have put in a MOSFET but I wasn't clear on what I was doing when I started.

Aside from "mostly everything" what do I not know that is not letting me set this up correctly?

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: Is this a complete schematic? Am suspecting there's some missing connections regarding RPi ground.

Comment: According to your diagram, your RPi is not powered...

Comment: Ahh, my apologies. This schematic is not completely diagrammed. The RPi has power and is functioning normally. At the moment, it is powered from a separate USB connection though. I've updated the question to add clarity.

Comment: Is it just me or isn't Q1 the wrong way around? I'd like to see some documentation for the ESC, I have very little experience with them.

Comment: @pipe I thought it was the wrong way too at first glance, but it makes sense when you think about it.

Comment: @castis does the battery's ground and the ground of the raspberry pi share ground?

Comment: @pipe I'm not 100% sure which way the transistor should have been oriented so I had tried it both directions, neither worked as I expected. If the E should be pointed towards the ESC then I'll reverse it when I get home today and experiment with that.

Comment: @HarrySvensson they currently do not. The Pi is being powered via a separate USB connection.

Comment: @castis no it's pointing the right way, it's just a very odd way to put it, _usually_ the arrow points downwards or to the right, left is.. it's like seeing a car in england. "Oh no, they are driving on the wrong side".

Comment: Well then, if they are not sharing ground, then there's your answer. I'm aware that you're powering the RPi with USB, but you can still solder a ground line from the USB and connect it to the battery's negative pole to form a complete circuit with the ESC & NPN & control signal.

Comment: Pi and ESC must have their grounds connected for this to work.

Comment: How much current is Q1 supposed to pass?

Comment: @HarrySvensson if the answer is as simple as that then I feel ridiculous! I'll attach the 5v lines to feed the Pi tonight and see if that does it.

Comment: This is why sharing a schematic is **vital** to a question. Instead of 18 minutes... it could take 18 hours... if this is the problem. Though your schematic could use some more work for quality. Because I'm still not 100% sure. Nowadays people got phones that take reasonable good quality, if it's not the problem that we assume, then go for a picture of your setup.

Comment: @pipe:  I realize now that there needs to be a base current.  I assume that one has to be pretty high which is why you're concerned?

Comment: @HarrySvensson I understand that now, far more than I did when I originally asked the question. I appreciate you and everyone else being patience with me while I get this all figured out. Next time I'll know more of what to put in a schematic.

Comment: @pipe the ESC is rated for 15A which is what the transistor is rated for. Seems like a MOSFET is more of what I'm after though?

Comment: @castis why do you need to put the **whole** ESC in series with a transistor? Isn't the computer-part of the ESC separated from the part of the ESC that draws the 15A? I mean don't you have two positive connections and a common ground? One of the positive for the computer and one of the positive for the 15A. If I were you I would go with a simple small transistor and shut off the computer-part of the ESC, there's no need to put the whole thing in series with a transistor.

Comment: @HarrySvensson to configure the ESC, you apply full throttle while plugging in the power. Since the RPi and the ESC will be powered by the same source; the ESCs config window is closed by the time the RPi boots. As such, I wanted to be able to control power to them. The specific ESCs I have came with a manual in another language, support for them is nil, and I don't know if that information is 100% correct. These are all just for experimenting and playing around with so I've had to toy around with them to figure out that much.

Comment: @castis right \$\$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the basic ways of switching using either PNP / P channel MOSFET for high side switch or NPN / N channel MOSFET for a low side switch.

**At all times the ground (0V) of the battery and the rpi are common.**

[image]

*Note: R5 (1k0) is optional but is a useful if using a Darlington NPN (high gain) as it helps to pull down any leakage current through the PNP.*

Comment: I love looking at the low-side pics. It's like a giraffe, with the tall neck reaching up to its head at the PNP, where the voltage vistas are "high up" in the tree tops, which then is looking back down at the power device. But a necessary arrangement given the voltages involved.

Comment: @jonk, Whatever your drug dealer is hooking you up with, I want in on it. :-D

Comment: @winny Hehe. It's just how Jim's pic looks. You can see the body with its feed "grounded" (planted), and it's long neck rising up. Hard to miss, the way the pic is done! And I like to imagine the high tension above the RPi as being "high up" like the tree tops might be on a savanna. Too high for the RPi to reach. But not too high for the giraffe! ;)

Comment: @jonk I know who's "high up" alright.

Comment: Jlm, why can't he just do it with one NPN/NMOS transistor? Isn't this for the controller part of the ESC? It makes **no** sense to put the **whole** ESC in series with a transistor.

Comment: Dang! Thank you so much for going this far out of your way to help me. I've got some new parts to acquire and some experimenting to do at home. From what I've gathered, the MOSFET is better suited to switch on a higher amp application?

Comment: @castis No, not necessarily. One often uses what one is more thoroughly familiar with (quick, easy, and already know the details to handle.) Unless there is a technical reason to go a different way. If equally familiar, then it's just other constraints in the project (like cost.) In this case, none of us knows enough to argue either case. So you can pick your poison and be successful, I think.

Comment: @castis One problem with the 3055 NPN in particular is that it can take close to 1 A through the base to get it to drive 15 A. That's something to think of when trying to drive it with a simple I/O...

Comment: @pipe I appreciate that, and I definitely would like to avoid pulling that much through the pi. Is that information derived from specs about the transistor? Ive been looking through the datasheet for the last few minutes and I can't seem to find information along those lines in there.

Comment: @castis This comment thread is getting a bit long but look for a "hFE" chart, which drops below 20 for high currents in the 2N3055, meaning that you have to push 1 A through the base to get 20 A through the collector.